# How to prevent row selection on click event on GridView in Yii

Tags: yii

I need to prevent the row selection on a click event on a CGridView in Yii MVC;

If I can catch the click event on all `tr` tags, this is enoght.

How can I catch the event and stop it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question:

```
$("tr").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```